# Implementing CSP into ASP web app

Tags: content-security-policy

We're trying to implement CSP into one of our sites and although we understand how to allow or not allow scripts, we're still confused on the nonce/sha* part. We have outside scripts such as bootstrap and jquery that come with the integrity="sha*" and that inline scripts or styles should be avoided. Everything inline should be refactored into an external file.

The question we have is, do we create a sha* key/nonce-* for every js or css file in our site (not external) or just putting 'self' after script-src/style-src in the Content-Security-Policy is sufficient?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need nonces for linked JavaScript files; they authorize inline Script tags.  The “self” (or URL) authorize the linked files.  The cleanup you have to do is get rid of “onclick” attributes in the HTML.  The SHA hashes are there to verify the integrity of the linked files.

So:

- Clean up inline “onclick” (and similar), and “style” attributes.
- Use nonces for inline script (and style) tags.
- Use SHA hashes for linked scripts from outside sources